# Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useId')

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am trying to run my `PromptGenerator` function, and got this error `- error Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useId')`.
Full error message/ warning is:

```
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
- error Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useId')
```

- The function call is at the `top-level` in the function component as shown.
- Would it matter if my app's structure is `pages/api/fileName.js` rather than `pages/app/page.tsx`?

My full code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useChat } from "ai/react";

export default function PromptGenerator() {
  const { messages, input, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useChat({
    api: "./chat_bot",
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {messages.map((m) => (
        <div key={m.id}>
          {m.role === "user" ? "User: " : "AI: "}
          {m.content}
        </div>
      ))}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Say something...
          <input
            id={2}
            className="fixed w-full max-w-md bottom-0 border border-gray-300 rounded mb-8 shadow-xl p-2"
            value={input}
            name="formInput"
            placeholder="Describe your business..."
            onChange={handleInputChange} // updating the input state
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any and every comment is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

While debugging, I tried to isolate sections in the code to catch the issue, and I believe this is the part that is throwing the error:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useChat } from "ai/react";

export default function PromptGenerator() {
  const {
    messages: prompt,
    user,
    input,
    handleInputChange,
    handleSubmit: handleFormSubmit,
  } = useChat({
    api: "./chat_bot",
  })};
```

I am running the packages below with latest `NextJS and react` installed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@clerk/nextjs": "^4.16.1",
    "@clerk/themes": "^1.6.1",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.14",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.17",
    "@huggingface/inference": "^1.8.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.15.0",
    "ai": "^2.1.8",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "eslint": "8.37.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.7",
    "langchain": "^0.0.81",
    "next": "^13.4.7",
    "pdf-parse": "^1.1.1",
    "pgvector": "^0.1.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.20.1"
  },
```

Comment: Try adding "use client" to the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem in react js.

i think there is not problem with code. but there is problem with your module. which is by mistake installed at two different directories. that's why script is not running well.

i solve this problem by:

firstly run this command in your cmd with respect of project directory

> **npm ls react**

then you will see the output like(this is just an example. might be you got some other path where your script being duplicated.):

PS C:\Users\otherpath> npm ls react
**datass@0.1.0 C:\Users\otherpath**

```
├─┬ @emotion/react@11.11.1
│ ├─┬ @emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks@1.0.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-transition-group@4.4.5
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ @testing-library/react@13.4.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0
**
```

check that path and also verify the same module in **C:\Program Files**

if there both directory have the same module remove above users path module and your then run script again.

or you can restart your IDE software.

for more information you can check this link [here](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning).